# Groovy class extends parent implements interface, parent implements method in interface, overide error

Tags: groovy, overriding, extends, implements

Easier to explain with simplified code. I have the following interface

```
interface FooInterface{
public void foo()
}
```

I have the following JAVA parent class from a library (notice the final keyword):

```
class Parent {
public final foo()
}
```

Finally, the child class:

```
class Child extends Parent implement FooInterface{
}
```

This results in compilation error that I cannot override the final parent method in the child class, which technically I am not. I figure this is a groovyism I'm not familiar with. So my question are:

1. Why does the compiler think I'm overriding?
2. How can I get this to compile?

Comment: Ah the parent class is a java class, so I assume groovy is trying to rewrite it make it groovy.

Comment: I can't even encapsulate it to get around because the parent library has references to both the interface and to the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

can't reproduce

final method: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#get()

works fine in groovy 2.4.5

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

interface I{
    public boolean get();
}

public class B extends AtomicBoolean implements I{
}

def b=new B()
```